# HTML5 Audio: How to Play only a Selected Portion of an Audio File (audio sprite)?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, mobile-safari, html5-audio

I'm working on an iOS metronome web app. Since mobile Safari can only play [one sound at a time](http://24ways.org/2010/the-state-of-html5-audio), I'm attempting to create an 'audio sprite' - where I can use different segments of a single audio track to generate different sounds. I have a 1 second clip with 2 half-second sounds on it.

```
<audio id="sample" src="sounds.mp3"></audio>

<a href="javascript:play1();">Play1</a>
<a href="javascript:play2();">Play2</a>
<a href="javascript:pauseAudio();">Pause</a>

<script>
var audio = document.getElementById('click');

function play1(){
    audio.currentTime = 0;
    audio.play();

    // This is the problem area
    audio.addEventListener('timeupdate', function (){
        if (currentTime >= 0.5) {
            audio.pause();
        }
    }, false);
}   

function play2(){
    audio.currentTime = 0.5;
    audio.play();
}

function pause(){
    audio.pause();
}
</script>
```

See it on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e72bW/4/).

As you can see, I've attempted to use the 'timeupdate' event ([jPlayer example](http://groups.google.com/group/jplayer/browse_thread/thread/c92f09c0db2ca580?fwc=1)) with no avail.

I've seen [Remy Sharp's post on audio sprites](http://remysharp.com/2010/12/23/audio-sprites/), but (A) I wasn't able to get it to work for me, and (B) I would prefer to stay away from a library dependency.

Any ideas?

---

***Update***

I now have it working using `setInterval`:

```
function play1(){
    audio.currentTime = 0;
    audio.play();
    int = setInterval(function() {
        if (audio.currentTime > 0.4) {
            audio.pause();
            clearInterval(int);
        }
    }, 10);
}    

function play2(){
    clearInterval(int);
    audio.currentTime = 0.5;
    audio.play();
}
```

There are some issues with sequence and setting/clearing intervals, but for my purpose - it seems to work.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e72bW/5/)

P.S. If anyone has a fix for this, this could be used in Games and Interface Sound FX.

Comment: https://github.com/VJAI/musquito

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think there are a couple of problems here.

Firstly, you're adding an event listener every time the user clicks Play 1.

Also I think

```
if (currentTime >= 0.5) { ...
```

should be

```
if (audio.currentTime >= 0.5) { ...
```

This also works:

```
<audio id="sample" src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/222645/click1sec.mp3" controls preload></audio>

<a href="javascript:playSegment(0.0, 0.5);">Play1</a>
<a href="javascript:playSegment(0.5);">Play2</a>

<script>
var audio = document.getElementById('sample');
var segmentEnd;

audio.addEventListener('timeupdate', function (){
    if (segmentEnd && audio.currentTime >= segmentEnd) {
        audio.pause();
    }   
    console.log(audio.currentTime);
}, false);

function playSegment(startTime, endTime){
    segmentEnd = endTime;
    audio.currentTime = startTime;
    audio.play();
}
</script>
```

Comment: This is a great solution demonstrating good features.  Please not, though, that intervals should probably be on the order of whole seconds.  Testing it in Chrome, I found that the browser will frequently blow past the intervals by as much as 0.4 seconds without an apology.

Comment: @Sam Dutton i tried using my own dropbox link and for some reason its not playing. its a .mp3 file

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a clean function to play segment of an audio object so this is what I come up with. It will also solves the the following error which will occur if the user click multiple triggers within short amount of time.

"Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause()"

```
const audioObj_1 = new Audio('/some_audio_file.m4a');
playSegment(audioObj_1 , 1.11, 2.45); // this will play from 1.11 sec to 2.45 sec

function playSegment(audioObj, start, stop){
    let audioObjNew = audioObj.cloneNode(true); //this is to prevent "play() request was interrupted" error. 
    audioObjNew.currentTime = start;
    audioObjNew.play();
    audioObjNew.int = setInterval(function() {
        if (audioObjNew.currentTime > stop) {
            audioObjNew.pause();
            clearInterval(audioObjNew.int);
        }
    }, 10);
}
```