# Sound from previous position playing before playback continues from specified position in html audio tag

Tags: html5-audio

I am making a HTML5/javascript browser game and I have problems with my audio.

I have all my clips in a single mp3 file to minmize the number of requests sent and when I want to play a clip I seek to the clips starting position (audio.currentTime = startTime) and play (audio.play()) when the audio tag fires the "seeked" event via an event listner.

When I pause playback I use the audio.pause() method.

The problem I have is that, before the sound I want to play starts, a split second of the file is played from where the audio was playing before the seek.

Anyone else that has encountered this problem?

Anyone know what to do about it?

Comment: Could you provide a few more details?
In which browser does this happen?

Comment: I mostly use mobile safari. I have a single mp3 containing several sounds separated by a few secs of silence.
When i seek in the file and then play i get a split second of sound from the beginning of the file before the playback position is updated properly (not all the time, mainly the first time)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Safari, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9811429/html5-audio-tag-on-safari-has-a-delay?rq=1) might be your problem.

Also, I'm finding that Web Audio API is looking more and more appealing (see my [possible answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11708317/splitting-an-html5-audio-object-into-multiple-audio-objects/11982417#11982417) to my own question, haha)

Edit: 
Lastly, if you want to stick with the whole HTML5 Audio object, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932412/html5-audio-how-to-play-only-a-selected-portion-of-an-audio-file-audio-sprite) might point you in a different direction.

Comment: I'm afraid none of these really capture my problem. I have no real problem starting or stopping the audio per se. The problem is that when I start the audio after setting the playback position (with `seek()`) I get a split second of audio from the previous playback position when i do `play()`